# Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $A∈\mathscr{M}_{n×n}(\mathbb{C})$, show that $A$ and $A^T$ are similar.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $n$ be a positive integer. If $A∈\mathscr{M}_{n×n}(\mathbb{C})$, show that
$A$ and $A^T$ are similar.

I have that $A=BC$ where $B,C$ are symmetric, then  $A^T=(BC)^T=C^TB^T=CB$ and then $AB=BCB=BA^T$ but I'm not sure if $B$ is nonsingular, or if I should try another way.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know about Jordan canonical form?

Comment: I saw a proof where the Jordan cannonical form $J$ was descomposed as $J=RS$ where $R,S$ are similar, but then I have the question that if $R$ and $S$ commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints: You just need to prove it for the Jordan blocks that have $\lambda$ on the digonal and $1$'s above. Conjugation with the antidiagonal matrix that has $1$'s on the antidiagonal should do the job.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand when you say "Conjugation with" that means conjugate the product or the subtraction of the matrices?

Comment: Let $I$ be the matrix that has 1's on the antidiagonal. The inverse matrix is also $I$. Conjugation by $I$ I mean the map $X↦IXI$.

Answer (score 4):

A way different from the one you are trying to use (but useful in the sense that it explicitly uses a complete similarity-invariant) is this:

Jordan canonical form's theorem yields that, if $\mathbb{F}$ is an algebraically-closed field, two matrices $A,B\in \mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})$ are similar if and only if

> $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^+,\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{F},\ \, \dim\ker\left((A-\lambda I)^n\right)=\dim\ker\left((B-\lambda I)^n\right)$$

Now, since $\forall C\in\mathcal{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{F})\ \dim\ker C^T=\dim\ker C$, and $(A-\lambda I)^T=A^T-\lambda I$, the result follows.